# Fill next column until it reaches zero in numpy matrix or pandas dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, vectorization

Imagine a table with known dimensions. The first column holds numbers and the rest of the rows are 0. I would like the fill the rows based on the value in the first column by subtracting 1 and stop in the column where the value is 0. I would like this to be as efficient as possible

The code I have now uses ndarrays and a loop :

```
test = np.zeros([3,360])
test[:,0] = [1,180,360]
for j in range(1,360):    
    test[:,j] = test[:,j-1]-1
test[np.where(test<0)] = 0
```

Is there a more efficient/pythonic way ? E.g. avoiding the for-loop ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A compact and reasonably fast way would be

```
np.maximum(0, np.subtract.outer([1,180,360], np.arange(360)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import time

time1 = time.time()
for x in range(1000):
    test = np.zeros([3,360])
    test[:,0] = [1,180,360]
    for j in range(1,360):
        test[:,j] = test[:,j-1]-1
    test[np.where(test<0)] = 0

duration1 = time.time()-time1
print 'It took ' + str(duration1) + ' seconds to run this.'

time2 = time.time()
for x in range(1000):
    test2 = np.zeros([3,360])
    test2[:,0] = [1,180,360]
    for i in range(0,len(test2)):
        test2[i,:test2[i,0]] = np.arange(test2[i,0],0,-1)

duration2 = time.time()-time2
print 'It took ' + str(duration2) + ' seconds to run this.'
```

The output:

```
It took 3.9154958725 seconds to run this.
It took 0.0595190525055 seconds to run this.
```

So it was almost 66 times as fast!

Comment: I'm not sure your speed gain will remain when you increase the number of rows.

Comment: I don't think so, but for this example it was faster

Answer (score 0):

This the way I will do

```
test = np.zeros([3,360])
test.fill(-1)
test[:,0] = [1,180,360]

np.clip(np.cumsum(test,1),0,360)
Out[1373]: 
array([[   1.,    0.,    0., ...,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 180.,  179.,  178., ...,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 360.,  359.,  358., ...,    3.,    2.,    1.]])
```